# Is there a way to select all rows created today(current date), if that column has time format date and time?

Tags: python, sqlite, date, where-clause, substr

If I have a table that contains:

```
table_id    id_from_other_table    date_time_when_this_row_was_added
[(1,        200,                   '2023-01-06 08-11-21')]
[(2,        200,                   '2023-01-07 07-21-21')]
[(3,        200,                   '2023-01-07 08-10-10')]
```

Can I get all the rows that were created at today's date which comes from:

```
today_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

although the time format for values inside that columns are in this time format ? :

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

I did the query like this:

```
id = 200
today_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND date_time_when_this_row_was_added LIKE ?%'
cursor.execute(query, (id, today_date)
```

But the returned list is empty.
What I want is to get all rows created today if there are any and return the most recent row created today.
I know how the get the most recent row created today, but I don't know hot to get all rows that were created today regardless the time.

I tried this query too and list returned is still empty:

```
id = 200
today_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND DATE(date_time_when_this_row_was_added) = DATE(?)'
cursor.execute(query, (id, today_date)
```

Comment: did you try to put today_date as `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")` ?

Comment: I will try now but I don't understand what %S will hold.

Comment: I know how to get the most current row created. I don't know how to get all rows created today regardless the hour that were created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite there is [no datetime data type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so your datetimes are actually strings.

Although the format that you use to store the dates is not the proper ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, you can use the string function [`SUBSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to extract the date part of the datetimes and compare it to the current date which you can get with SQLite's function [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so there is no need to use Python code to get the current date and pass it as a parameter to the query:

```
query = """
  SELECT * 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE id = ? 
    AND SUBSTR(date_time_when_this_row_was_added, 1, 10) = date()
"""
cursor.execute(query, (id,))
```

or, if you want the current date in local time:

```
query = """
  SELECT * 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE id = ? 
    AND SUBSTR(date_time_when_this_row_was_added, 1, 10) = date('now', 'localtime')
"""
cursor.execute(query, (id,))
```

Comment: Thank you. subset(column_name, 1, 10) = date() is what I looked for but didn't know if exist or how to write it.